# Django permissions mixin on CBV, how to apply on 'publish blog' method

Tags: django, permissions, mixins, python-decorators, django-class-based-views

I'm quite new to Django, and I use the Django's CBVs. Currently I'm applying the permissions to my project by using the LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin etc. On the views it works perfect! However, I've got a few methods that are function-based.

For example, to publish a blog via an URL

> /blogs/1/publish

is bound to

```
url(r"^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/publish/$", views.publish, name="publish"),
```

which calls

```
def publish(request, pk):
    if request.method == "GET":
        Blog.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(publish_date=datetime.datetime.now())
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/blogs/" + pk)
```

Since I use class-based-views, all of my views can be protected with the mixins. On function based, I'm not sure what the appropriate method would be to protect these.

Should I someway convert these function based methods to a class or
should I create method decorators which check the permissions for these occasions? Or is there an other method which is more convenient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too ways are possible:

1. create CBV for publish and override post method:

   ```
   class PublishView(UpdateView):

       model = Blog

       def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
           pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
           Blog.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(publish_date=datetime.datetime.now())
           return HttpResponseRedirect("/blogs/" + pk)
   ```

   2. Inside the Blog UpdateView define publish as staticmethod:

```js
     class BlogUpdateView(UpdateView):

            model = Blog

            @staticmethod
            def publish(request, pk):
               if request.method == "GET":
               Blog.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(publish_date=datetime.datetime.now())
               return HttpResponseRedirect("/blogs/" + pk)
```

in urls you access your function directly your publish method

```
url(r"^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/publish/$", views.BlogUpdateView.publish, name="publish"),
```

Answer (score 2):

Django has decorators like [`login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.permission_required) and [`permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator%60) decorator, which you can use for function based views. These have actually been in Django much longer than the mixins for CBVs which were added in Django 1.9.

```
@permission_required('myapp.can_publish')
def publish(request, pk):
    if request.method == "GET":
        Blog.objects.filter(pk=pk).update(publish_date=datetime.datetime.now())
    return HttpResponseRedirect("/blogs/" + pk)
```

As an aside, it's normally best practice to use a POST request for an action like changing the published date.

Comment: How sloppy of me, I completely missed on the django's built-in permission decorator. Thanks. And also thank you for the tip!